What is the maximum outstanding in Bus interface?
I am wondering what the maximum outstanding is and how to calculate the maximum outstanding number.
Especially, for the case of AXI interface, how to know the maximum outstanding? Is it usually just same with the number of transaction IDs (like AWID, ARIW)?
Please let me know this.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@Community (or whoever voted it as lacking a [mcve]) - this isn't a debugging question.  It's not asking about code.  We don't require an attempt for questions like this.  That said, it's not 100% clear, like do you want code that can figure this out at run-time, or do you want to figure it out yourself looking at data sheets for a known device or something?

And I heard that the maximum outstanding is static information when we have already design some architecture. So I would like to the general way to calculate the maximum outstanding number.

AXI is a pipelined protocol.  What do you mean by maximum outstanding?  This can depend on the peripheral.  Ie, it may buffer data and the buffer would be one definition of 'maximum outstanding'.  So, to that definition, it is source dependent.  The maximum transfer rate is the bus clock (1 transfer/clock) as opposed to APB, etc.
